# Error in if elif loop

Tags: python

I have 3 columns with values and if the value of one is twice than the other any of the pair, the list should append the index.

`0 1 2 3
A 1 2 3
G 2 3 4
K 1 1 2
T 1 1 1`

The result should be [A,G,K]

I am getting a Key error in the below loop:

```
percentage = pd.concat([percent1, percent2, percent3], axis=1, join='inner')
percentage = percentage.reset_index()
AA= []
for i in range(0, len(percentage)):
    if percentage[1][i] == 2*percentage[2][i]:
        AA.append(percentage['index'][i])
    elif percentage[2][i] == 2*percentage[3][i]:
        AA.append(percentage['index'][i])
    elif percentage[1][i] == 2*percentage[3][i]:
        AA.append(percentage['index'][i])
```

Comment: Don't just say "I am getting a Key error", give us the actual error. It tells you, among other things, which line the error was on and what the key was. You also need to show us what's in `percentage`—ideally by just replacing the first two lines of your code with a simple `percentage = <some pandas expression using nothing but constants>`.

Comment: post stacktrace and sample data of percent1,2,3

Comment: @abarnert I did try to include the error but it is not taking since its hug. The error is in the line - if percentage[0][i] == 2*percentage[1][i]:, the error is Keyerror 1. Please let me know how can I post the entire trace.

Comment: @Prateek, the sample data is as given in the example above in the post.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your actual error is that you're using columns 1, 2, and 3 on the right side of your comparisons, but you don't have 4 columns, only 3. So, this line:

```
elif percentage[1][i] == 2*percentage[3][i]:
```

… will raise a `KeyError(3)` on that `percentage[3]` part of the expression.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to fix that, because I can't figure out what your code is intended to do, and you haven't explained it.

The most obvious guess would be that you wanted to use columns 0, 1, and 2 on the right. But that will just give you an empty list, not… a list of three rows, or whatever it is you wanted. And, given that you're using columns 0, 1, and 1 on the left rather than 0, 1, and 2, I'm not sure how obvious the guess was in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to the columns name. The concat function keeps the column names as it is and this error was due to those same column names.